# Dart isolate group implementation

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I'm trying to understand how memory and processes like garbage collection are implemented in isolate groups in Dart.

The article [Introduction to Dart VM](https://mrale.ph/dartvm/) at the time of this writing includes the following image:

[image]

However, this image was made prior to isolate groups that entered the stable branch in Dart 2.15. My question is, *what has changed internally about the image above after the addition of isolate groups?*

Related research:

- https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36097
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47164
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46754
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXT7nir1B48
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUMjt0AxVHU